# Why am I getting this error when trying to configure make?

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

I need to install make as a static linked program so that I can install an updated version of glibc without my system crashing. After unpacking with tar and passing `./configure` inside the directory I get this configure error:

configure:4216: error: in '/home/anon/make-4.3':
configure:4218: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log for more details

Here's some information from my config.log:

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3177: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3245: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3256: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3311: result: yes
configure:3460: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3499: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3506: checking for gawk
configure:3522: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3533: result: gawk
configure:3544: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3566: result: yes
configure:3595: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3612: result: yes
configure:3744: checking whether make supports the include directive
configure:3759: make -f confmf.GNU && cat confinc.out
this is the am__doit target
configure:3762: $? = 0
configure:3781: result: yes (GNU style)
configure:3851: checking for gcc
configure:3867: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3878: result: gcc
configure:4107: checking for C compiler version
configure:4116: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4127: $? = 0
configure:4116: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 
configure:4127: $? = 0
configure:4116: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4127: $? = 1
configure:4116: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4127: $? = 1
configure:4147: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4169: gcc -static -02 -g   conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-02'
configure:4173: $? = 1
configure:4211: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU make"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "make"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU make 4.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-make@gnu.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/make/"
| #define PACKAGE "make"
| #define VERSION "4.3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4216: error: in '/home/anon/make-4.3':
configure:4218: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log' for more details
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a gcc issue, not a make issue.  It seems your GCC command line doesn't like that option.  It works for me:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

$ echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > foo.c

$ gcc -static -O2 -g foo.c

$ ldd a.out
        not a dynamic executable
```

Does this not work for you?  What version of GCC are you using?  What operating system?

However, it might be simpler to choose a different method of handling this problem than building a static make.

Why don't you copy your current libc to somewhere else then run make with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like:

```
$ mkdir ~/oldlibc
$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ~/oldlibc
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/oldlibc make
```

or something like that?  Use `ldd /usr/bin/make` to see what shared libraries your version links and where they're from.

Comment: I'm using version 9.3.0 of gcc on Ubuntu, I tried the command you posted and gcc successfully created the foo file and the install file. But why doesn't it do that when using `./configure`? Could it be something to do with the files I'm trying to compile with?

Comment: »»C compiler cannot create executables«« : Have you got a full install of gcc? `sudo apt install g++` will install dependencies making gcc work fully. I.e. `libc6-dev, linux-libc-dev` etc.

Comment: I can't explain it.  If you run `type -a gcc` does it show just the one version?  Maybe you have an alias or function wrapper for GCC, or maybe there are multiple versions and your PATH is reset?

Comment: Knud Larsen: Yes I have g++ already as well as the dependencies, I'm installing something as we speak and there was no trouble when using `./configure` or `make` and `make install`.

Comment: MadScientist: After running `type -a gcc` I get `gcc is /usr/bin/gcc` and `gcc is /bin/gcc`.

Comment: Ah, I upgraded to the latest version of bash and successfully configured and installed make. Problem solved.

Comment: Well, one thing you didn't tell us is how you're invoking the `./configure` command.  Please show the command line you used.  If you're doing something like `./configure CC='gcc -static'`, that's a bad idea.  Use instead `./configure CFLAGS='-static -O2 -g'` so the option goes with the flags, not the compiler.

Comment: The latest version of bash?  You mean, you used **apt** to update to the latest version?  Or you built it yourself?  I find it extremely odd because configure scripts are supposed to work with all sorts of very old, decrepit shells with all sorts of bugs.